# How would I order by 2 values, QTY of item and alert median (when the item gets below this point they're notified)

Tags: mysql, sql, math

So what I'm trying to do is select * items from the database and order them so the items which have the least stock based on there alert median and qty are at the top of the results!

I have two tables (`stocklist` and `items`). stocklist holds the quantity and alert, while the item table holds the item name and what category it's assigned to. I am

I have tried the following SQL statement but it gave me funny results :\ I am selecting all items where the HHID is 36.

```
SELECT items.*, stocklist.quantity, stocklist.alert
FROM stocklist,
     items
WHERE items.iID = stocklist.iID
  and items.hhID = 36
ORDER BY (stocklist.quantity / stocklist.alert) ASC
```

#### Updated

See how I've got QTY = 3 and alert = 0? This shouldn't be displayed at the top, it should be displayed below the other items!

Here is a snapshot of the results I got:
[image: results]

#### FIX:

I will make sure that alert cannot be 0!

Comment: Funny results? In which way?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

- I would suggest making an INNER JOIN and a well defined join condition instead or the "natural" join you wrote in youre query statement.

Secondly:

- Are You sure that the value of quantity/alert is the right one to get the leas stock? Shouldn't quantity be the only parameter that is relevant? What information does the alert value hold?

Try this:

```
SELECT items.*, 
       stocklist.quantity, 
       stocklist.alert, 
       (stocklist.quantity /stocklist.alert) AS result

FROM stocklist 
       INNER JOIN items ON items.iID = stocklist.iID
    WHERE items.hhID = 36 AND stocklist.alert > 0

ORDER BY result ASC
```

Comment: Well in the app Im creating, all the items that are running low should be at the top. If the item QTY is equal to the alert median then it will be displayed in orange, if the qty is = 0 it will be displayed in red, and if it's > than the alert median it will be green!

Comment: Actually, what I should do is make sure that the alert cannot be = 0!